# Edit distance in C function called in Python does not return the correct result

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to test the call to a C (edit distance) function in Python, to compare the execution time with a similar function written in Python, it's pure curiosity and a way to understand the C/Python articulation.

Here the implementation of the Levenshtein distance in C (source : [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C)) in `_distance.c` file :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int min(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if(a <= b && a <= c)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else if(b <= a && b <= c)
    {
        return b;
    }
    else if(c <= a && c <= b)
    {
        return c;
    }
}

int levenshtein(char *s1, char *s2) {
    unsigned int x, y, s1len, s2len;
    s1len = strlen(s1);
    s2len = strlen(s2);
    unsigned int matrix[s2len+1][s1len+1];
    matrix[0][0] = 0;
    for (x = 1; x <= s2len; x++)
        matrix[x][0] = matrix[x-1][0] + 1;
    for (y = 1; y <= s1len; y++)
        matrix[0][y] = matrix[0][y-1] + 1;
    for (x = 1; x <= s2len; x++)
        for (y = 1; y <= s1len; y++)
            matrix[x][y] = min(matrix[x-1][y] + 1, matrix[x][y-1] + 1, matrix[x-1][y-1] + (s1[y-1] == s2[x-1] ? 0 : 1));

    return(matrix[s2len][s1len]);
}
```

Then I created a `_distance.so` file, and I call my function as follows :

```py
from ctypes import *

so_file = './_distance.so'
dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(so_file)

# source text
reference = """
Ne vous défiez jamais de votre voisin de gauche qui a une chemise de grosse toile, une cravate blanche, un habit propre, 
mais de drap commun ; suivez plutôt très-attentivement les mouvemens de ce voisin de droite, dont la cravate est bien 
mise et fine, qui a de grosses breloques, des favoris, un air d’honnête homme, le parler hardi ; 
c’est celui-là qui vous volera votre mouchoir ou votre montre. 
"""

# target text with errors
hypothesis = """
Ne NOOOS défiez jamais de votre voisin de Gauche qui a une chemises de grosse toile, une cravate blanche, un habit propre, 
mais de drap commun ; suivre plu très-attentivement les Mouvemens de ce voisin de droite, dont la cravate est bien 
mise et fine, qui a de grosses breloques. 
"""

print(dll.levenshtein(reference, hypothesis))
```

which returns me `0` as a result, while i will have to recover `132` (The result of my Python function).

I can't figure out if this is from the C code, the type of input variables to `dll.levenshtein ()`, or an error in using `ctypes` package?

thank you very much for your help

[EDIT]

I tested my `levenshtein()` function in C code directly:

```
int main()
{
    char *ref = "Ne vous défiez jamais de votre voisin de gauche qui a une chemise de grosse toile, une cravate blanche, un habit propre,",

    *target = "Ne NOOOS défiez jamais de votre voisin de Gauchate blanche, un habit propre,";
    int result;

    result = levenshtein(ref, target);
    printf("%i", result);

    return result;
}
```

and I have an output with a result.

So I think this came from my call in Python code.

Comment: Did you raise the warning level to the maximum? -- Anyway, you might like to write a C test program to check your C functions.

Comment: I don't really understand why I have a bad vote for my question, but ok ... there is still some research behind this question and a goal

Comment: `dll.levenshtein.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]`, `reference = b"""...`, `hypothesis = b"""...`, (before `dll.levenshtein(...` ).

Comment: Not defining `.argtypes` and `.restype` is the #1 reason for ctypes problems.  Ctypes has to guess at argument types otherwise.  You're passing Unicode strings instead of byte strings.

Comment: FYI A simple debug check is to use a debugger or print `s1` and `s2` in the C code to verify it was passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Python string is not `char*` in C, which points bytes, especially if you are using Python 3.

You should convert a Python string to bytes before you pass it to C.

```
# source text
reference = """
...
""".encode('utf-8')

# target text with errors
hypothesis = """
...
""".encode('utf-8')
```